# How to convert Java Pattern to Postgres regex

Tags: java, regex, postgresql

Is there a way to programmatically convert in java a `java.util.regex.Pattern` to a `String` containing a Postgres compatible regex, that could be used with `SIMILAR TO`?

Comment: There is no built-in method. Also note that `SIMILAR TO` does not support regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Well I know that SIMILAR TO does not like regex at all...so I think you are stuck there if you must use that. 
Check out Pattern.quote() for the rest. 
Good luck!